# Twitter social login issue with Azure AD B2C - Forbidden

Tags: twitter, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c

I am trying to add Twitter social login for an Azure AD B2C tenant. I followed the below instruction from Microsoft
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/identity-provider-twitter?pivots=b2c-user-flow

While I try to test the user flow I am getting error as follows.

> The request to obtain a token from 'https://api.twitter.com/oauth/request_token' returned an error 'Forbidden'

[image]

I have re-created the Twitter credentials just to make sure that this issue is not because of the credentials. I have checked almost everything I can, but the issue remains the same.

Also I can't find any further details about the above error by the correlation id shared by Azure AD. I have checked all the logs available in Azure B2C and I can't find any traces about this error.

I have created a .net sample using the same twitter credentials and the social login works without any issue.

So this issue seems to be something related to Azure B2C specifically. Any pointers for sorting out this issue will be much appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***I tried to reproduce the same in my environment and got below results:***

I have one user flow named **`B2C_1_SUSI`** where I added **Twitter** as identity provider before running it like this:

[image]

I got login screen including **Sign in with your social account** after selecting `Run user flow` like below:

[image]

When I clicked on **`Twitter`**, I got **same error** as you like this:

[image]

The error usually occurs if there is something wrong in added
**`Callback URI / Redirect URLs`** of **User Authentication settings** page.

As mentioned in this [MS documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/identity-provider-twitter?pivots=b2c-user-flow#create-an-application),

> You need to use all **lowercase letters** when entering your tenant name and user flow name even if they are defined with uppercase letters in  Azure AD B2C.

When I checked the same in Twitter Developer Portal's **User Authentication settings** page of application, user flow name is in uppercase like below:

```
https://sritestb2caad.b2clogin.com/sritestb2caad.onmicrosoft.com/B2C_1_SUSI/oauth1/authresp
```

[image]

To **resolve** the error, I changed user flow name to **lowercase** as mentioned in the document like this:

```
https://sritestb2caad.b2clogin.com/sritestb2caad.onmicrosoft.com/b2c_1_susi/oauth1/authresp
```

[image]

After saving it, I ran the userflow again where I got **below screen** to authorize application like this:

[image]

When I clicked on **`Authorize app`** button, it redirected me to **User Details** page successfully like below:

[image]

In your case, check whether you added  **`Callback URI / Redirect URLs`** of **User Authentication settings** page in correct format or not by clicking **`Edit`** button beside it like this:

[image]

Comment: Hi @Sridevi Thanks a lot, yes it was exactly the issue with upper case.